# Hyper-V VMs no longer working with status Paused-Critical

Tags: hyper-v

We have a VM server which has been working well for years now.  I was using a VM from it just 3 weeks ago.  Today I look and see all VMs on it are set to status "paused-critical"

In the event log there is a message: 
*The parent partition uses a different VMBus version. You need to Install a matching VMBus version in this guest installation.*

Any ideas?

[image: Hyper-V Manager]

Answer (score 1):

Fouund it - this was simply because the disk holding the VMs only had 26MB free.  Removed some old VM's and now all is well.  I hope this answer will be helpful to the next person who experiences this.